# Transfer Evolution Settings

Tags: settings, evolution

I have Evolution (mostly) set up on my desktop.  I want to import the settings (mail servers, IMAp subscriptions and especially junk learning) to my new laptop.

ETA: I have several gig of old email in the Local Folders so I can't just back it all up and restore it from Evolution's full backup.

Is there any way to do this?  Without full backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Evolution, but this sounds promising:

https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/backup-restore.html.en

---

**Edit** after the new information about the existing local mails:

If your local mails are in the way, this might help:

https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/data-storage.html.en

If I understand this correctly, the mails are in `$HOME/.local/share/evolution`.

So I'd try to terminate Evolution, move that directory away for the moment and *then* use Evolution's backup function, copy that backup to the other machine, terminate Evolution and then move the directory back to its old name.

Comment: Sorry - I looked at that.  I left out a critical item.  Let me update my OP

Comment: Now that might do it.  I will try that soon and report back.

Comment: This worked - the caveat is, there are a few files in there you have to leave alone or Evolution will try to create new ones.  But all the files named like my large Archives folders, are fine.  I moved them out, backed up to <50M, and moved them back without a hitch.